# is it possible to calculate the standard error when using the relevel function in CoxPH model?

Tags: r, survival, inference, cox-model

Based on the results table of the existing CoxPH model, is it possible to calculate the standard error when using the relevel function?

Like this...

when 2 vs. 1(ref),

exp(coef) 0.96712/0.97700 = 0.9898874

se(coef) ??/?? = ??

```
> coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Trt, data = data)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Trt, data = data)

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z     p
Trt1 -0.02327   0.97700  0.02451 -0.949 0.342
Trt2 -0.03343   0.96712  0.02856 -1.171 0.242

Likelihood ratio test=1.48  on 2 df, p=0.4777
n= 10000, number of events= 10000 
> data$Trt <- relevel(data$Trt, ref = '1')
> coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Trt, data = data)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Trt, data = data)

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z     p
Trt0  0.02327   1.02354  0.02451  0.949 0.342
Trt2  "Unknown" "Unknown"  "Unknown"  "Unknown"  "Unknown"

Likelihood ratio test=1.48  on 2 df, p=0.4777
n= 10000, number of events= 10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's going on with `relevel()` here (and the answer is probably a software-specific matter off-topic on this site). There's a more generally useful way to get the standard errors of combinations of coefficient estimates in a Cox or other regression model, which doesn't require refitting.

The formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) is the key. I find it least error-prone to work in the original coefficient scale and leave the transformation to hazard ratios until the end. For your difference between `Trt2` and `Trt1` with corresponding coefficients $\beta_2$ and $\beta_1$, the variance estimate is:

$$\text{Var}(\beta_2-\beta_1) = \text{Var} (\beta_2) + \text{Var} (\beta_1) -2\text{Cov}(\beta_1,\beta_2),$$

where $\text{Cov}$ is the covariance between the estimates. The `vcov()` function applied to the model output returns the variance-covariance matrix for the coefficient estimates. The individual variances will be the squares of the `se(coef)` values, but you'll need to use `vcov()` to get the covariance.

Once you get the variance for the difference, the square root is the standard error. The point estimate of $(\beta_2-\beta_1)$, plus/minus 1.96 times the standard error, gives the standard 95% confidence interval in the coefficient scale for a Cox model. Exponentiation puts those into the hazard-ratio scale.

Working with the single original model, instead of trying to refit with releveled multi-level factors, is a general strategy that extends better to more complex models than this. Post-modeling tools, for example those in the R [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) and [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) packages, are designed to help with this.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I will try your suggestion.